# Update one element of big list without re render others elements in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-hooks, use-state, renderer

i want to optimize my react App by testing with a large list of `li`
Its a simple todo List.

By exemple, when click on a `li`, task will be line-through, and check icon will be green. This simple action is very slow with a large list because, the whole list is re render.

How to do this with React Hooks?

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => inputRef.current.focus(), []);

//Pseudo Big List
  useEffect(() => {
    const test = [];
    let done = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      test.push({ task: i, done });
      done = !done;
    }
    setList(test);
  }, []);

  const handlerSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTask = { task: input, done: false };
    const copy = [...list, newTask];

    setList(copy);
    setInput("");
  };

  const checkHandler = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const copy = [...list];
    copy[index].done = !copy[index].done;
    setList(copy);
  };

  const suppression = (e, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    const copy = [...list];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setList(copy);
  };

  const DisplayList = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {list.map((task, index) => (
          <Li
            key={index}
            task={task}
            index={index}
            suppression={suppression}
            checkHandler={checkHandler}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  //JSX
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>TODO JS-REACT</h1>

      <form id='form' onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='Add task'
          required
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          value={input}
          ref={inputRef}
        />
        <button type='submit'>
          <i className='fas fa-plus'></i>
        </button>
      </form>

      {list.length === 0 && <div id='noTask'>No tasks...</div>}

      <DisplayList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Li component

```
import React from "react";

export default function Li(props) {
  return (
    <li
      onClick={(e) => props.checkHandler(e, props.index)}
      className={props.task.done ? "line-through" : undefined}
    >
      {props.task.task}
      <span className='actions'>
        <i className={`fas fa-check-circle ${props.task.done && "green"}`}></i>
        <i
          className='fas fa-times'
          onClick={(e) => props.suppression(e, props.index)}
        ></i>
      </span>
    </li>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-babbage-kp3md?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question, as @Dvir Hazout answered, I followed [this article](https://staleclosures.dev/preventing-list-rerenders/) and made your code the changes you need:

```
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

  //Pseudo Big List
  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = [];
    let done = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      arr.push({ id: uuidv4(), task: randomWords(), done });
      done = !done;
    }
    setList(arr);
  }, []);

  const submit = ({ inputTask }) => {
    const newTask = { task: inputTask, done: false, id: uuidv4() };
    setList([newTask, ...list]);
    reset(); //clear input
  };

  const checkHandler = useCallback((id) => {
    setList((list) =>
      list.map((li) => (li.id !== id ? li : { ...li, done: !li.done }))
    );
  }, []);

  const suppression = useCallback((id) => {
    setList((list) => list.filter((li) => li.id !== id));
  }, []);

  //JSX
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TODO JS-REACT</h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <input type="text" {...register("inputTask", { required: true })} />

        <button type="submit">
          <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </form>

      {list.length === 0 && <div id="noTask">No tasks...</div>}

      <ul>
        {list.map((task, index) => (
          <Li
            key={task.id}
            task={task}
            suppression={suppression}
            checkHandler={checkHandler}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Li component

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

const Li = memo(({ task, suppression, checkHandler }) => {
  // console.log each time a Li component re-rendered
  console.log(`li ${task.id} rendered.`);
  return (
    <li
      onClick={(e) => checkHandler(task.id)}
      className={task.done ? "line-through" : undefined}
    >
      {task.task}
      <span className="actions">
        <i className={`fas fa-check-circle ${task.done && "green"}`}></i>
        <i className="fas fa-times" onClick={(e) => suppression(task.id)}></i>
      </span>
    </li>
  );
});

export default Li;
```

You can check it [live here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-huge-todolist-forked-qu7kcx?file=/src/App.js)
I know it's probably late for your question, but may help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.memo` and wrap the `Li` component. This will cache the instances of the `Li` component based on shallow comparison. Read more in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Otherwise, if you don't need the state in the container, you can keep it locally in the `Li` component and then it won't cause a whole list rerender.

Comment: Hi, i already tested Li with React.memo, it was same thing, how move the state to Li component? I need it in App to generate Li, check it or delete it.

Comment: Then `memo` is what you need. Use `useCallback` for the functions you pass on to `Li` component so they'll not be recreated each rerender. then React.memo will work properly.

Comment: I tried, but il failed to use correctly useCallback, this is my codesandbox, can you change directly in?
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-babbage-kp3md?file=/src/App.js

Comment: All of your components are actually inside the app component and not independent.
First, separate them. then, use React.memo on these components, and then make sure you pass functions as props only when there're created with `useCallback`